# Adding Spring arguments to VSCode Debug launch.json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am working with a Java Springboot (2.1.2) application in VSCode. I have the debugger working and can run the application. However, I am having difficulty adding Spring specific arguments to the run command. I have looked around alot but can't seem to find anything on this.

I am trying to tell spring to use two application.yml files. The code I would use in the command line to actually run the application is:

`mvn spring-boot:run \
-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,classpath:/application-secret.yml`

I want to be able to add this argument to the vscode launch.json file.

My current launch file looks like this, but I have tried alot of different variations.

```
{"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug Blog Rest",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "com.example.BlogRestApplication",
        "args": [
            "-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,classpath:/application-secret.yml"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 16):

I actually just figured it out. I thought I had tried this before, but I guess not. I had to change it from `args` to `vmArgs`.

Updated file:

```
{"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug Blog Rest",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "com.example.BlogRestApplication",
        "vmArgs": [
            "-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,classpath:/application-secret.yml"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project root, go to /.vscode/launch.json, create if needed.
For program args, and vm args, enter like below:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "My Main",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "com.apu.MyMain",
        // be careful, same name as project folder name >>
        "projectName": "myproject", 
        "args": "cat dog mouse",
        "vmArgs": [
            "-DVMARG1=arg1",
            "-DVMARG2=arg2"
        ]
    }
]
```

}